# Superposition of curves in kibana

Tags: kibana

I am new to Kibana and I am trying to trace curves using line charts.
I have two parameteres (X-Axis the time and Y-Axis the hopCount), I need to visualize this for many nodes and I need to have all their curves in one graph (superposition curves).
How can I do this please?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible unless you're having **nodes** as a field within your ES record or either having it as a *scripted field*. Hence you can differentiate your line graphs by the field *nodes*.

Or else the other option would be to show all the distinct line graphs in one single **dashboard**.